# How to print 5 random alphanumeric strings on one click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, random, generator, alphanumeric

I am able to create single alphanumeric string at a time by clicking on a button by using Math.random() function.

But i need to print 5 alphanumeric random values at a time by clicking on button.
Please help me out I am beginner in javascript and got stuck.
I really need some solution for that

Comment: `for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) { ... do your logic ... }`

Answer (score 0):

This works by generating random numbers in base 10 then converting them to base 36, where digits include both numbers and letters (10 digits + 26 letters = 36).

```js
'use strict';
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
  const strings = new Array(5)
    .fill()
    .map(() => Math.random() * 10000)
    .map((n) => n.toString(36).replace(/\./, ''));
  console.log(strings);
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: Generating random number with `Math.random` between 65 and 100 (ASCII: A-Z and 10 more for the digits) and `useString.fromCharCode` to convert it to char. For getting the number subtratct the differnce in ASCII if the random is greater 90.  Use a for-loop and add the chars.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let random = '';
    for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        let randInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 65);
        random += String.fromCharCode((randInt<=90) ? randInt : randInt-43);
    }
    document.getElementById('random').textContent=random;
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Random</button>
<div id='random'></div>
```